# PHP and MYSQLi for <select> drop down

Tags: php

I have inserted group of values on MySQL column and select on php as results like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [custom_options] => 1,2,3,4 ) )
```

I need to insert this values `<select>` drop down now. What do I need to use `foreach` ,`for`, `while` to get results in `<select>` drop down?

Comment: You can use `explode()` to split and do a foreach ot generate the options.

Comment: Hi Bose, expects parameter 2 to be string, but this output from select query as Array ( [0] => Array ( [custom_options] => 1,2,3,4 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make another array depends on your value by explode() Example :

```
$arrayVarible = Array ( [0] => Array ( [custom_options] => 1,2,3,4 ) )
$explodeId = explode(',',$arrayVarible[0]['custom_options']);
$explodeName = explode(',',$arrayVarible[1]['custom_options']);

echo '<select>';
   for($i=0;$i<count($explodeId);$i++){
      echo '<option>'.$explodeId[$i].'</option>';
   }
echo '</select>';
```

**Update**

```
echo '<select>';
   for($i=0;$i<count($explodeName);$i++){
      echo '<option>'.$explodeName[$i].'</option>';
   }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: how to add $key value to this ? any idea

Comment: You can get $key value by calling $key . It's return to you the array key

Comment: kindly help me mate, I'm add auto select dropdown boxs, now i added another one select box not getting values for it 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [custom_options] => 1,2,3,4 ) [1] => Array ( [custom_options] => ram,suresh,sathish,nathans,joe ) )

Comment: i need subtract two select box from this query? can we done it ?

Comment: If you need another select box then you just generate another loop for another select box

Comment: Yes Mate I need like your asked

Comment: No Mate any idea please

Comment: Dear i have just updated my comment . Please have a look and let me know

Comment: but array coming from mysql as dynamic mate, what i need to do now ?

Comment: Just create an array with your table record and apply this

Answer (score 0):

**First You Need to explode the string with comma(,) then print it with a loop.**

```
$op=array(array('custom_options'=>'1,2,3,4'));
$val=explode(',',$op[0]['custom_options']); // Explode the string 
echo '<select>';
for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
    echo '<option>'.$val[$i].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: how to add $key value to this ? any idea